# Фотографии в новости вконтакте

Tags: php, javascript

В новости в соц.сети вконтакте, когда есть больше одной фотографии они распределяются определенным образом в этой новости, в зависимости от размера и количества. Как это осуществляется?
[image]

Comment: можно поиграться с Grid system bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько предустановленных схем размещения изображений.
Каждая схема поддерживает разное количество фотографий, и определенное сочетание соотношений длин и высот изображений.

1 фотка - во всю ширину стены (слишком высокая обрезается.)
2 фотки - два стоящих рядом изображения (широкие обрезаются, сочетание изображений широкого с высоким смещает стык в сторону высокого.)
3 фотки - другие схемы
и так 4,5,6..10 изображений, больше 10 схем.

В общем посмотри на свою стену, на стену друзей и проанализируй, как там располагаются изображения и какие. За тебя тут никто работу выполнять не будет.

Comment: там надо подключать JS? или можно все на php сделать?